# setting the length property of array

Tags: solidity

What does setting the `length` property of an array do? In most other languages `length` is a function that return the length of an array.

I have the following code:

```
struct ledger_t {
  uint8 WinningNum1;
  uint8 WinningNum2;
  uint8 WinningNum3;
  uint8 WinningNum4;
  bytes32 ClosingHash;
  bytes32 OpeningHash;
  mapping(address=>bet_t) bets;
  uint Guess4OutOf4;
  uint Guess3OutOf4;
  uint Guess2OutOf4;
  uint Guess1OutOf4;
  uint PriceOfTicket;
  uint ExpirationTime; //for eventual refunds only, ~2 weeks after draw announced
}
ledger_t[] public ledger;

//constructor
function TheEthereumLottery() {
  owner = msg.sender;
  ledger.length = 0;
  IndexOfCurrentDraw = 0;
  referral_fee = 90;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does setting the length property of an array do.

It sets the length of the array.

The proviso is that the array must be dynamic, and must be a storage rather than memory variable.

From the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html?highlight=array%20length#sometimes-when-i-try-to-change-the-length-of-an-array-with-ex-arrayname-length-7-i-get-a-compiler-error-value-must-be-an-lvalue-why):

> You can resize a dynamic array in storage (i.e. an array declared at
>   the contract level) with `arrayname.length = <some new length>;`. If you
>   get the “lvalue” error, you are probably doing one of two things
>   wrong.
>
> - You might be trying to resize an array in “memory”, or
> - You might be trying to resize a non-dynamic array.