# How to add values to array within a struct in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

First of all, sorry for my English as a Google Translate

I wanted to add values to the list inside the struct, but with the code below the following error appears: UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Ballot.Play memory [] memory to storage not yet supported.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;
contract Ballot {

    struct Play {
        uint cod_music;
        uint qtd;
    }

    struct Listener{
        address user;
        Play[] listened;
    }

    Listener[] listeners;
    Play[] tests;

    function listenMusic(uint cod) public {
        tests.push(Play({
            cod_music: cod,
            qtd: 1
        }));

        listeners.push(Listener({
            user: msg.sender,
            listened: tests
        }));
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change this:

```
listeners.push(Listener({
    user: msg.sender,
    listened: tests
}));
```

To this:

```
listeners.length += 1;
Listener storage listener = listeners[listeners.length - 1];
listener.user = msg.sender;
for (uint i = 0; i < tests.length; i++)
    listener.listened.push(tests[i]);
```

Or even to this:

```
listeners.length += 1;
Listener storage listener = listeners[listeners.length - 1];
listener.user = msg.sender;
listener.listened = tests;
```

Side-note: I haven't tested either one of them.

Comment: browser/StackExchange.sol:23:9: TypeError: Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays.
        listeners.length += 1;        
        ^--------------^

Comment: @JoãoVitor: It works on solc 0.4.25, and at least according to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13355/16043), it should be allowed. Not sure about solc 0.6.x. Sorry :(